# Cannot return the value from button

Tags: javascript

While console logging I'm getting 'undefined'. I'm curious to know why I can't return the value of the buttons. Is the event listener supposed be outside the function ? And also how can to get the value outside the function ?

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rpsButton');
const getPlayerChoice = () => {
  let something = '';
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = e => {
      something = e.target.value;
    }
  })
  return something;
}

console.log(getPlayerChoice());
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to log something to console. do it in the onclick handler. Your console log is invoked at runtime and not when elements are clicked.

Comment: i thought you were still in jail but anyway... it's not clear what you expect the function to return. functions are not what you think they are. they're called, processed and return a value.

Comment: Don't assign event listeners in a function that you are going to call more than once.

Comment: You need to learn how asynchronous code works... `return something;` runs way before the user ever clicks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're calling a function and, within that, attaching the listeners to the buttons - which is fine, and would make sense if the click handler was just logging the value, but you can't return a value from that handler, and then the function, like you want to.

So you *can* do this...

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rpsButton');

const getPlayerChoice = () => {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = e => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  });
}

getPlayerChoice();
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

...but this defeats the purpose of having a specifically-named function that I assume is meant to log the value.

Perhaps what you want to do is to log a value when that function (`getPlayerChoice`) *that has been assigned to a button's click listener* is called.

```js
// Cache the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rpsButton');

// Add a listener to each button. The listener calls
// the `getPlayerChoice` function when it is fired
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', getPlayerChoice);
});

// Log the value of the clicked element
function getPlayerChoice(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

A alternative solution would be to attach *one* listener to the `buttons` container to catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM (aka [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)). When a click event is fired the listener calls `getPlayerChoice`. It checks that the element that fired the click event is a button with a `rpsButton` class, and then logs its value.

```js
// Cache the buttons container, and add _one_ event
// listener to it. Like above the listener calls the
// `getPlayerChoice` function when fired
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
buttons.addEventListener('click', getPlayerChoice);

// Check that the clicked element has a `rpsButton`
// class, and then log its value
function getPlayerChoice(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.rpsButton')) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

Additional information

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Answer (score 1):

you weren't calling the function you were just doing the onclick events which is the only thing you need in this case. you can still save the value if you want to do something to it.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rpsButton');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = e => {
    let something = e.target.value;
    console.log(something)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
  <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could re-write the code in this way.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rpsButton');

const setupEvents = () => {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = e => {
      globalThis.something = e.target.value;
    }
  });
}

setupEvents();

const getPlayerChoice = () => globalThis.something;

console.log(getPlayerChoice());
```