# How can i return this string form onclick event inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, events

I'm trying to retun the button i pressed i can console.log it but it can't return

```
const playerSelect = () => {

  RPS = document.querySelectorAll(".rpsButton")
  RPS.forEach(i => {

     i.onclick = () => {

        return i.value
     } 
  })
}
```

return it to here and get comparison

```
const compare = (playerChoise()) => 
{
  if (getComputerChoice() == "rock" && playerChoise == "paper")
  {
    score++
  }
}
```

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="rpsButton" value="Rock">✊</button>
    <button class="rpsButton" value="Paper"></button>
    <button class="rpsButton" value="Scissors">✌</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Return it … to where?

Comment: @danh — `i` and `event.target` will have the same value in this case.

Comment: @DanielBlack — Those will give the same value as `i` in this case. The question is about **returning** a value from an event handler.

Comment: @Quentin - good point, and yeah, return it to where?

Comment: I think they want to do something like `const result = playerSelect();` and assign the value generated by the event listener attached by `playerSelect` to `result`.

Comment: [This is a dupe more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977396/cannot-return-the-value-from-button/73977703).